# Finding all sets which are not subsets of other sets

Tags: algorithms, sets, finite-sets

I have a set of sets, for example

```
{
 {1, 2, 3},
 {1, 2},
 {2},
 {2, 4}
}
```

I want to find all sets which are not subsets of another set. For example, `{2}` and `{1, 2}` are both subsets of `{1, 2, 3}`, so my answer would just be `{1, 2, 3}` and `{2, 4}`. Let's call these "max sets".

There is a clear brute-force solution to this, where you check every pair of sets in $O(n^2)$ comparisons. Are there any known algorithms which do better than this?

Thoughts:

- You can sort the list to avoid checking if a larger set is a subset of a smaller set, but this doesn't improve the asymptotic complexity.
- Constructing a DAG out of the subset relations and performing a topological sort to find the max sets would still require examination of every pair.
- You can eliminate a subset as soon as it is discovered, without checking it against the rest of the sets. I'm unable to derive any average-case complexity guarantees about this though, because an eliminated set may only have been a subset of a single max set.

Comment: I am unsure how your solution in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ works. Are you considering that testing if a set is a subset of another can be done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time?

Comment: @Nathaniel There are $O(n^2)$ subset comparisons; the amount of time for each comparison will depend on set size, but is probably irrelevant for the purposes of this question (could be wrong though!). To be pedantic, the brute force algorithm takes $O(n^2 m)$ time where $m$ is the size of each set, and $n$ is the number of sets.

Comment: Although this just popped up as a related question, and the answer seems to suggest that the brute-force solution is the best we've got: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12806/114645

Comment: Not sure that this helps any, but set inclusion creates a partially ordered set, and Wikipedia has a Hasse diagram of it on their page for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg It also seems $O(n^2)$ is optimal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560659/efficient-algorithm-to-find-the-maximal-elements-of-a-partially-ordered-set